# Unable to read XML to object

Tags: c#, xml, object, serialization

I could use some help in reading this xml as an object in C#, the problem I have is with "ExtensionData" element, I can read everything in this xml except what's inside that element and I can't understand why, also I am receiving this xml the way it is, I can't alter it in any ways. I've tried pasting it as classes in visual studio, aswell as converting it using various websites but none of them were able to convert that node in an object.

```
<BufferEntitiesContainer>
    <HeaderComandaBufferEntities>
      <HeaderComandaBufferEntity>
          <ProfilImportId>25</ProfilImportId>
          <OrderNumber>999872748</OrderNumber>
          <OrderDate>2021-03-12</OrderDate>
          <BuyerILN>12345600</BuyerILN>
          <BuyerName>CLIENT B2C</BuyerName>
          <SalesDepartment>Vanzare WEB</SalesDepartment>
          <Warehouse>A01</Warehouse>
          <OrderCurrency>RON</OrderCurrency>
          <DocumentFunctionCode>WB2C</DocumentFunctionCode>
          <Remarks></Remarks>
          <PaymentType></PaymentType>
          <DeliveryPointILN>CIP-NX</DeliveryPointILN>
          <OrderSerial>WB2C</OrderSerial>
          <PaymentTerm></PaymentTerm>
          <ExpectedDeliveryDate>2021-03-12</ExpectedDeliveryDate>
          <ExtensionData><![CDATA[<ExtensionData>
          <ExtensionFields>
            <ExtensionTemplateID>3</ExtensionTemplateID>
                <Fields>
                    <Root>
                      <Avans>0</Avans>
                      <PerioadaValabilitate dataInceput="1900-01-02" dataFinala="2078-12-31" />
                      <DS_CLIENT_ID>--</DS_CLIENT_ID>
                      <Nume_client>DAN NEDELCU</Nume_client>
                      <Adr_cod_post>011618</Adr_cod_post>
                      <Adr_judet>BUCURESTI</Adr_judet>
                      <Adr_loc>SECTOR 1</Adr_loc>
                      <Adr_str>NAUM</Adr_str>
                      <Adr_nr>1</Adr_nr>
                      <Adr_bl>1</Adr_bl>
                      <Adr_et>1</Adr_et>
                      <Adr_ap>1</Adr_ap>
                      <Adr_sect></Adr_sect>
                      <Nr_tel>0744835647</Nr_tel>
                      <Inf_gen>--</Inf_gen>
                      <Tip_pl>false</Tip_pl>
                      <Link_fact>--</Link_fact>
                      <Taxa_tr>0</Taxa_tr>
                      <Cupon_reducere>0</Cupon_reducere>
                      <CNP></CNP>
                    </Root>
                </Fields>
          </ExtensionFields>
     </ExtensionData>]]></ExtensionData>
          <OrderLines>
              <DetaliuComanda>
<BuyerItemCode></BuyerItemCode>
<EAN>LEDLC-A6010E27/BC-WL</EAN>
<Remarks>Bec cu led A60 E27 10W 230V lumina rece Basic Well</Remarks>
<OrderedQuantity>1</OrderedQuantity>                                      
<OrderedUnitNetPrice>8.8353</OrderedUnitNetPrice>
<UnitOfMeasure></UnitOfMeasure>
<Warehouse>A01</Warehouse>
</DetaliuComanda>
          </OrderLines>
      </HeaderComandaBufferEntity>
</HeaderComandaBufferEntities>
</BufferEntitiesContainer>
```

Comment: The `ExtensionData` element is effectively just a string, and I'd expect it to be represented as a string in your object model - you'd then need to parse the XML *within* that string separately.

Comment: I've noticed that, but I don't know how to convert that text to another object...

Comment: Speaking to the reason *why*, CDATA is used in xml typically to transport data that would otherwise make an invalid xml document. As mentioned, its value is a string, not xml unless you then take another step to parse it as such.

Comment: Well I need that data to insert it in various fields so I have to parse that string to an object.

Comment: You would do it the same way you are parsing the original document. Pull the value out as a string, then parse that string as xml and deserialize it to your object.

Comment: Try following :             XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement ExtensionDataCDATAelement = doc.Descendants("ExtensionData").FirstOrDefault();

            string ExtensionDataCDATAstr = (string)ExtensionDataCDATAelement;
            XElement ExtensionDataCDATA = XElement.Parse(ExtensionDataCDATAstr);

Comment: The key concept here is that CDATA represents a simple string. So you need to parse it to an object after you parse the complete XML file. However, as @Crowcoder pointed out, the purpose of CDATA is to represent data that may not be valid XML, so you may run into trouble there.

Comment: 1) Do the contents of the `<ExtensionData>` embedded string have a fixed XML schema?  2) What XML serializer are you using -- `XmlSerializer` or something else?

Comment: I am using XmlSerializer, and I am waiting for a feedback from the company that sends me the XML, hopefully the CDATA is always a valid xml document.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to parse the string to an object this way:

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BufferEntitiesContainer));
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader($@"{salesOrdersPath}{file}");
BufferEntitiesContainer so = (BufferEntitiesContainer)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(streamReader);
Console.WriteLine(so.HeaderComandaBufferEntities.HeaderComandaBufferEntity.ExtensionData);

XmlSerializer xmlInnerSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ExtensionData));
StringReader reader = new StringReader(so.HeaderComandaBufferEntities.HeaderComandaBufferEntity.ExtensionData);
ExtensionData soInner = (ExtensionData)xmlInnerSerializer.Deserialize(reader);

Console.WriteLine(soInner.ExtensionFields.Fields.Root.Nume_client);
```

So if anyone has this problem again, the solution was I made an object of type ExtensionData then I deserialized the inner xml string using StringReader to that object.

Thanks to all the people who gave me advices.